# Animated GIF ins't displayed with Qt on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, windows-7, gif

I am trying to make animated GIF work on Qt 4.7 and 4.8, it just doens't work on windows:
- worked well on Linux
- worked well on Windows on Wine
- but the image didn't show up on Windows XP and Windows 7, but works with PNG

This is my code:

```
QMovie *movie = new QMovie(":/resources/loading");
QLabel *myLabel = new QLabel(this);
myLabel->setMovie(movie);
movie->start();
```

Comment: Did you forget ':/resources/loading **.gif**'?

Comment: Not really, I forgot to mention that ":/resources/loading" is an alias of the GIF image (you can give an alias to every QT resource). I used also with PNG and it worked, and also used the filename ":/images/loading.gif" and ddidn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, sorry for my bad english. I managed to solve this in 3 steps. I don't know whether it is correct way to do it but it works!

1. Create a folder name 'imageformats' in the same directory of your application.
2. Copy qgif.dll from your qt plugins directory and paste to the folder.
3. Put your gif files in the same folder.

Note:
But make sure to set your current path of QMovie's object correctly. 
For e.g :
eye_right = new QMovie(QDir::currentPath()+"/imageformats/eye_right.gif");

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 8, although it works even normally (without any additional dll) on Windows 8.1..

Comment: I only needed to create the folder imageformats and place de dll there. You can still use the resource system and have the gif compiled in the exe. How on earth did you find out about that dll?